# What is the verb after "two of something"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I came across the below sentence but it got me thinking why there's a singular verb after a plural.

> **Two** shots of Vodka **is** what I would be happy with.

Comment: Vodka is the Subject. Since vodka is an uncountable noun, "Is" is used.

Comment: @Luciferangel No, *shots* is the subject; *vodka* is the object of the preposition. But *two shots* is still singular.

Comment: When a plural subject is conceived as a single idea or goal, it is frequently more natural to use a singular verb. *Two days on the beach is all I need to recover.* Or:  *Two rounds of golf is what I'm aiming for.* Or: *Two wives is one wife too many.*